# How to index through argv[1] in C?

Tags: c, argv

If I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int length = strlen(argv[1]);
```

and argv[1] one is just a word, for example, "hello", how can I index through it backwards and print out letter by letter?

I tried using strrev, but apparently this isn't in linux and rather than include the function I'd rather just for loop through argv[1] backwards.

I tried:

```
int i;  
for (i = length; i == 0; i--){

    printf("%c", argv[1][i]);
}
```

but I knew this would be wrong before I even executed it.

Comment: You're on the right track. Think carefully about how the for statement works.

Comment: Your problem is unrelated to argv[1].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I index through it backwards and print out letter by letter

```
int i;  
for (i = strlen( argv[1] ) - 1 ; i >= 0; i--){
    printf("%c", argv[1][i]);
}
```

Also, of course you need to `#include <string.h>` for string-related functions like `strlen`.

Comment: When you count down like this, make sure your variable is not an unsigned type, otherwise it will never finish.  (It's easier to forget than you might think.)

Answer (score 1):

The function `strlen` will return the number of characters in the array/string, however, the last element will not be the value returned but rather `length = strlen(argv[1]) - 1`

Also i believe with your `for` loop you meant:

```
for (i = length; i >= 0; i--){ //Note the change of i==0 to i >= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer is somewhat ok, this should not be left like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int length = strlen(argv[1]);
```

This is incorrect on 3 accounts:

1. no check whether there is argv[1] in the first place, preferably
   fixed by making sure argc == 2
2. strlen is used, but string.h is not included. are you sure you are compiling with warnings enabled?
3. a somewhat stylistic but still important remark is that if you are going to use argv more than once (and you are), the string should be stored somewhere. in general you don't want to rely on argv nor argc after initial stage of parsing arguments

Comment: For #2, what does it mean if I get the warning but it still runs?

Comment: It means you are playing with fire, and if it runs, you got lucky. A technical answer is too involved to included here and I don't know any good thing to link. Just make sure you always compile with warnings and fix them. You are setting yourself up for a spectacular failure otherwise.